# How to add html-file with JavaScript code in template Slim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, slim-lang

There are **HTML**-file that contains **JavaScript** code. This **JavaScript** code loads an image and positioning it in a certain place. If failed, a message displays.

I need to include this file in template **Slim**.

I can include one **Slim** template to another by the following:

```
=render 'some/path/some_pattern'
```

How to include **HTML**- file to my template **Slim**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to add some javascript to your slim file is either by including the javascript file using

```
= javascript_include_tag 'name of the file'
```

or by directly adding the javascript code to your slim file, using

```
javascript:
  code line 1
  code line 2
  ...
```

Comment: I'm trying to include javascrip files to my slim template but this is not working for me. Do you happen to have other solutions? My JS files are in the assets pipeline and i used the Slim gem to convert my ERB to Slim and after than, my JS files stopped working. thank you.